# Extract selective records

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table like this:

```
Table A             
Customer    InvoiceNo       Region  Type    Amount
A001        10001           Europe  FG      100
B001        10002           Asia    FG      200
C001        10003           America MISC    50
D001        10004           Asia    FG      300
A001        10005           Europe  MISC    20
C001        10006           America MISC    10
B001        10007           Asia    FG      300
```

I wish to split the `Amount` into 2 columns, namely `Sales_Amt` & `Misc`. The `Region` is not required.
The result that I wish to have should look like this:

```
Customer    InvoiceNo       Type    Sales_Amt MISC
A001        10001           FG      100       0
B001        10002           FG      200       0
C001        10003           MISC    0         50
D001        10004           FG      300       0
A001        10005           MISC    0         20
C001        10006           MISC    0         10
B001        10007           FG      300       0
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're going to have to format your input and desired output better (text/html table) in order to get helpful answers.

Comment: i'm not sure i am fully understanding the question...why don't you simply select the desired columns from Table A?

Comment: AH, now I see, where does Region come from?

Comment: I wish to split the 'Amount' from Table A into 2 columns, namely 'Sales_Amt' & 'Misc'. The 'Region' is not rq'd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty simple:

```
select
    Customer, 
    InvoiceNo, 
    Type, 
    decode(Type, 'MISC', 0, 1) * Amount as Sales_Amt, 
    decode(Type, 'MISC', 1, 0) * Amount as Misc
from
    TableA
;
```

Comment: Error msg: Error: SQL0204 - DECODE in *LIBL type *N not found. (State:S0002, Native Code: FFFFFF34)

Comment: Use the equivalent for your DBMS. Because you never mentioned what DBMS you are using, I can't tell you how the method is named.

Comment: You can use the CASE expression

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Customer,InvoiceNo,Type,
        Case when TYPE!='MISC' Then amount Else 0 End as Sales_Amt,
        Case when TYPE='MISC' Then amount Else 0 End as Misc
From TabalA
```

Comment: `WHEN Type='MISC'` the condition should be.